# CSS Transition from height auto to height 75%

Tags: css, height, transition

I made a css transition which is from height auto to height: 75%.

CSS-Transition:

```
-webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

But its not working in IE and Firefox. I found some posts on google, but couldnt find a solution.

Thanks four your help.

Comment: If my answer was not usefull, please provide more code, or better, JSFiddle example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with `%` and `auto` you can try with `min-height` like this:

```
div {
  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
div:hover {
  min-height:75%;
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H4kVy/)**

<sub>Tested in Chrome 31 -- Firefox 26</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Try  this: [transition example](http://jsfiddle.net/hLc3Y/4)

CSS:

```
.tran{
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    height: 100px;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    height: 100%;
}

.tran:hover{
    height: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="height: 200px;">
    <div class="tran">
        Example
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user2207770 Does this answer your question? If so, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, change from height to min-height or max-height, what ever will better for your needs.

Example:[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Kuk6S/)